# unable to get asp:Checkbox ID for jquery in .net c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, selector

Does anyone know what is it going on here? I have the following code in my aspx file:

```
<tr>   
    <th class="graytext r">Add Reps to Team:</th>
    <td>           
     <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" DataSourceID="dsEmployees" EnableViewState="false" GridLines="None" CssClass="clGridDirectory">
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="employee_name" Text='<%# Eval("fullname") %>'/> 
                  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="employeeidToRep" Value='<%# Eval("employeeid") %>'/>
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="repID" Text='<%# Eval("rep_id") %>'  CssClass="cl_required_for_sale" data-messages="{required:'required'}" />
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqvrepID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="repID" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="required" />
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsEmployees" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="app_staff_without_team_select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>        
    </td>
</tr>
```

I try to get a alert once the user clicked on the checkbox by using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= employee_name.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        alert('bingo')
    });
</script>
```

But somehow the error message display when I'm trying to run the page :

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'employee_name' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:    

Line 121:  <script type="text/javascript">
Line 122:      $('#<%= employee_name.ClientID %>').click(function () {
```

Does anyone know what is it going wrong with my jQuery code? How could I only able to get the checkbox id for the jQuery?

Comment: How you tried adding this in `document.ready` part ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the CheckBox's ID (which isn't suitable inside a template anyhow), use the `Checkbox.CssClass`, e.g.:

```
CssClass="employee_name"
```

Then, in jQuery, the selector is `'.employee_name'`, e.g.:

```
$('.employee_name').click(function() { alert('id: ' + this.id); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do using

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox onclick="javascript:alert('clicked')" runat="server" ID="employee_name" Text='<%# Eval("fullname") %>' />                       
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add JS function on `onclick event of CheckBox`

Answer (score 0):

Attach function to the Checkbox click form the code behind file i.e RowDataBound event. rather than doing it directly it wont work like that.

**or** you javascript is like

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, 
                    GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.FindControl("FordelingCheckBox");

            checkBox.Attributes.Add("onclick","javascript:alert('clicked')");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way. The jQuery selector below will add event handler to all check-boxes with ID ending with 'employee_name'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            $(':checkbox[id$="employee_name"]').change(function () {
                alert('bingo');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: using class selector is even better because in grid view, each ID gets numeric suffix like employee_name1, employee_name2 and so on, added on run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Because the check box is in a control that repeats data (a repeater) the id of the check boxes generated by the grid view is dynamic and not static (the first row will have id = employee_name_0 or different depending on the clientIdMode property).

In order do add the event handler to the check box you need to select the check box differently, eiter by css class or something else.

Additional Note: If you want to use the other controls inside the item template you cannot select them by their ID because of the same reason you can't select the check box by id. To do this you will need to add a css class to the needed controls and add a selector that will select the siblings of the check box controll that have the specific class.